# invalidation of std::function objects

Tags: c++11

The following code does not work as per my understanding. When the `Raise`
 method of the handler object is called, random (I assume uninitialised variable) values are printed. My suspicion is that the `map::insert` calls made in `CreateTests` results in some sort of move that results in the invalidation of `this` parameters provides to the `std::function` objects provided to `EventCoordinator::Register`. The intended output of this program would be 2 lines printed in the console, with values `0` & `1` printed. Can somebody advise what the error here is?

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class EventCoordinator
{
    using Handler = std::function<void()>;
    using Handlers = std::vector<Handler>;

    std::map<int, Handlers> HandlerMap;

public:

    void Register(const int id, std::function<void()> handler)
    {
        HandlerMap[id].emplace_back(handler);
    }

    void Raise(const int id)
    {
        try {
            auto handlers = HandlerMap.at(id);
            for (const auto& handler : handlers) {
                handler();
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception& e) {
            std::cout << e.what();
        }

    }
};

class test
{
public:
    test() : mId(-1)
    {
        std::cout << "test default constructor\n";
    }
    test(const int id, EventCoordinator& handler) : mId(id)
    {
        handler.Register(mId, std::bind(&test::func, *this));
    }

    void other()
    {
        std::cout << this << '\n';
    }

    void func() const
    {

        std::cout << this <<'\n';
        std::cout << mId << '\n';
    }
    ~test() = default;
    test(const test& other) = default;
    test(test&& other) noexcept = default;
    test& operator=(const test& other) = default;
    test& operator=(test&& other) noexcept = default;
    int mId;
};

std::map<int, test> CreateTests(EventCoordinator& handler)
{
    auto returnMap = std::map<int, test>();
    returnMap.emplace(std::make_pair(0, test(0, handler)));
    returnMap.emplace(std::make_pair(1, test(1, handler)));
    return returnMap;
}


int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    EventCoordinator handler;
    auto ret = CreateTests(handler);
    handler.Raise(0);
    ret[0].other();
    handler.Raise(1);
    ret[1].other();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: When you use this function member `void Register(int id, std::function<void()> handler)`, you are passing the handler by value (i.e. copying). Is this your intention or you would like passing by reference? `void Register(int id, std::function<void()> & handler)`

Comment: I don't wish to store the `function<void()>` object anywhere else except for in the event coordinator. So a copy here would be fine I assume. I am not sure if the `emplace_back` calls in the `EventCoordinator::Register` functions result in another copy, or if the `handler` argument is moved into the vector.

Comment: Nitpick: `Register` can be simply `HandlerMap[id].emplace_back(handler);`

Comment: @Caleth - right you are. I did think that I was going to be able to refactor the registration. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function:

```
std::map<int, test> CreateTests(EventCoordinator& handler)
{
    auto returnMap = std::map<int, test>();
    returnMap.insert({ 0, test(0, handler)});
    returnMap.insert({ 1, test(1, handler)});
    return returnMap;
}
```

you create two temporary `test` classes. These go out of scope when `CreateTests` returns.

In `main()`,

```
auto ret = CreateTests(handler);
handler.Raise(0);
handler.Raise(1);
```

`func` is called, and `test::mId` is accessed, but does not exist anymore, hence the corrupted values.

Comment: Really? I thought that these would be copied into the `std::map<int,test>` object, which is then returned and capture, maybe even NVRO would occur. Can you provide a test proving your observation?

Comment: `Handler` is a `std::function<void()>`, and `std::bind(&test::func, this)` does not copy the `test` class, so the temporary is never copied.

Comment: no, but the `ret` variable is a `std::map<int,test>`. This is where the created `test` objects will continue to live.

Comment: yes, but you call `handler.Register` and `std::bind` in the constructor of the temporary. Then a copy is inserted into the map, but the bound `this` still refers to the temporary.

Comment: So i need to move the temporary into the `std::map<int,test>`?

Comment: No, the moved object will also have a different `this`. You could call `handler.Register` in a separate function, on the `test` objects in the map.

Answer (score 1):

As per the suggestion of @alain, the registration of the `test` object could not be carried out in the constructor of the `test` object. A `register_test` method was added to the `test` class. The following code takes the initialised `std::map<int,test>` object and calls `test::register` on the objects stored in the map.

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class EventCoordinator
{
    using Handler = std::function<void()>;
    using Handlers = std::vector<Handler>;
    std::map<int, Handlers> HandlerMap;

public:

    void Register(const int id, std::function<void()> handler)
    {
        HandlerMap[id].emplace_back(handler);
    }

    void Raise(const int id)
    {
        try {
            auto handlers = HandlerMap.at(id);
            for (const auto& handler : handlers) {
                handler();
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception& e) {
            std::cout << e.what();
        }
    }
};

class test 
{
    int mId;
public:
    test() : mId(-1)
    {
        std::cout << "test default constructor\n";
    }

    test(const int id) : mId(id)
    {}

    void register_test(EventCoordinator& handler) {
        handler.Register(mId, std::bind(&test::func, this));
    }

    void func() const
    {
        std::cout << mId << '\n';
    }

    ~test() = default;
    test(const test& other) = default;
    test(test&& other) noexcept = default;
    test& operator=(const test& other) = default;
    test& operator=(test&& other) noexcept = default;
};

void RegisterTests(std::map<int,test>& testCollection,EventCoordinator& coordinator)
{
    for (auto& test: testCollection){
        test.second.register_test(coordinator);
    }
}

std::map<int, test> CreateTests(EventCoordinator& coordinator)
{
    auto returnMap = std::map<int, test>();
    returnMap.emplace(std::make_pair(0, test(0)));
    returnMap.emplace(std::make_pair(1, test(1)));
    RegisterTests(returnMap, coordinator);
    return returnMap;
}


int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    EventCoordinator handler;
    auto ret = CreateTests(handler);
    handler.Raise(0);
    handler.Raise(1);
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few tries, I found the little error.

When you use `Register` member function in the `Test` constructor, you use the pointer `this`, but you need the reference, not the pointer so, change `this` for `*this` and I think that the code runs properly:

```
 test ( const int id , EventCoordinator& handler ) : mId ( id )
  {
    handler.Register ( mId , std::bind ( &test::func , *this ) );
  }
```

Comment: Your solution works. But the `test` object held by the `std::function<void()>` object, is not the same as the `test` object held by the `std::map<int,test>` object that is returned from `CreateTests`. See my edits

Comment: Well. This is because test is copied... Because the constructor of bind use the copy contructor of test.

Comment: Yeah I should have been more explicit. I need the `test` object referred to by the `std::function` object to be the same as the one held by the `std::map<int,test>`. Thanks for your suggestions though.